# When is it okay to ask about a character's sexual orientation?

Tags: discussion, scope

We've gotten two questions in the past few hours that ask if a character in a TV show is gay:

- [Is Major Nelson gay in I Dream of Jeannie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26414/is-major-nelson-gay-in-i-dream-of-jeannie)
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26429/is-dr-mccoy-gay-in-star-trek

The former is currently upvoted and has two well-received answers; the latter was swiftly closed. However, I'm not seeing the difference between the two. Is there a difference between them? Why or why not?

Comment: There's also this question from a few months ago: [Does Star Trek ever allude to Sulu's sexual orientation?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21270/does-star-trek-ever-allude-to-sulus-sexual-orientation)

Comment: Another one: [Is Ianto gay in Torchwood](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26466/is-ianto-gay-in-torchwood)

Comment: Unfortunately, even on the Internet, homosexuality is a touchy subject. It's sad Society can't just grow up.

Comment: It isn't the subject of the question that's the problem - but the quality and intent. The Sulu question is quite well-written, whereas the Torchwood and McCoy seem to be nothing but trolls.

Comment: @HorusKol I disagree with you about the Sulu question. The only basis for the question is that the actor is gay, which is *not* a basis for asking a question about a character. Do we want to allow users to ask if a character plays chess because the actor does? If a character is a democrat because the actor is? It's not a good basis for  a question, and falls under "Not A real Question" imo.

Comment: hmm... I didn't really take in the second paragraph when reading the question - maybe if that was dropped and the question asked without the allusion to the actor's orientation then that would be better? I don't see a problem with the question beyond that

Comment: @Wipqozn wow - as the author of the Sulu question, your comments here give me real pause.

Answer (score 16):

Hmmm, difficult. One of these sets off my troll vibe and the other one doesn't. However, one was posted by a new user while the other was posted a known and respected user of the community. I can't be sure that this doesn't influence me.

I can objectively see a difference in the presentation. Both questions present flimsy clues, but what they do with them is different. The [Major Nelson qeuestion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26414/is-major-nelson-gay-in-i-dream-of-jeannie) asks the question in a neutral tone. The [Dr McCoy question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26429/is-dr-mccoy-gay-in-star-trek) is more of a case of “your answer is provided along with the question” and “it is a rant disguised as a question” — some of our [signs of questions not to ask](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) (it starts with “There is plenty of evidence to conclude”!).

So far the Dr McCoy has had several flags in addition to the visible close votes. The Major Nelson question has a single close vote.

I don't see anything intrinsically wrong with asking about a character's sexual orientation, like you might ask any other question that has some bearing on understanding an SF work. It is of course a sensitive subject, bound to attract both trolls and overreaction against them, so we must tread with caution.

Comment: @Wipqozn Oops, yes, I did, thanks.

Comment: If you want a bias check - I fully agree with the fact that the later was a troll. And you know that I'm extra-unbiased against new users and anything that can be borderline non-awful question. +1.

Comment: I genuinely thought it would be really neat if Major Nelson was a serious attempt at showing the unfortunate reality of being gay in that era. But the evidence doesn't support it, it seems.

Comment: The McCoy question read like flamebait.  Never thought it was serious question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything wrong with asking after a character's sexual orientation at any time. If we can ask if some character wears a hat, then why not sexual orientation? Regardless of the topic, our community is pretty good about shutting down trolls.

Comment: ... *pondering if one can finagle a research grant to study relationships between characters in hats and sexual orientation*

Comment: Probably. Try the University of Woo-Woo. :D